# Using macrovariables in calculus with arrays SAS

Tags: arrays, loops, sas

I would like some help with SAS Arrays and do loops

I have some code which nearly works and would like an explanation why it doesn't work as expected.  I wish to calculate the max of the elements in an array taking a limited number values determined by a variable calculated.

```
DATA VALUES;
INPUT VAL;
DATALINES;
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
;
RUN;

%macro prueba(dataset);
DATA PRUEBA;
SET &dataset;
ARRAY DIAS(11) V1-V11 (4 5 6 7 8 9 10 88 75 46 71);
k = _n_ + 1;
IF k le dim(DIAS) THEN 
%DO i = 1 %TO k;
Maxi = max(of V1 - V&i);
%END;
RUN;
%MEND;
%prueba(VALUES);

The error message:
A character operand was found in the %EVAL function or %IF condition where a numeric operand is required. The condition was: 
       k 
ERROR: The %TO value of the %DO I loop is invalid.
ERROR: The macro PRUEBA will stop executing.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you that the upper bound for your `%DO` loop is a character string instead of a number. The macro processor sees `k` as constant text.

Just use a regular `DO` loop instead.

```
%macro prueba(dataset);
DATA PRUEBA;
  SET &dataset;
  ARRAY DIAS(11) V1-V11 (4 5 6 7 8 9 10 88 75 46 71);
  k = _n_ + 1;
  do i=1 to min(k,dim(DIAS)); 
    Maxi = max(maxi,dias(i));
  end;
RUN;
%MEND;
```